# What is the Rails query to select records where an array field has at least N elements

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

For a Rails app, using Postgres, with a model `Foo` with a field `bar` that is an array of strings, how do I find records where bar has at least N elements?

So given:

```
# schema.rb
t.string "bar", default: [], array: true
```

how can I find records where bar has, say, more than 3 elements?

```
# wrong:
Foo.where("COUNT(bar) > ?", 3) # this is NOT valid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

`Foo.where("ARRAY_LENGTH(bar, 1) > 3")`

Check [official doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-array.html).

Comment: even reading the "docs" it's confusing, but that works, so thanks! (The docs calling that second parameter "int" is useless; nowhere is it explained.)

Comment: @jpw, the second parameter is the dimension I guess. if your array is one dimensional, you'll pass 1, if 2D, then pass 2. Not sure though. :)